# script bash acrivate conda enPython automatically

Tags: python, bash, conda

I want to activate my enviroment using script bash. This my scripten:

```
#! /bin/bash
export SPARK_HOME="/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/"
source conda activate /home/mapr/miniconda3/envs/envPython
```

What is wrong in this script.
when i run this command in terminal work correctly.
Output expected:

```
bash scripten #i have to get my envPython conda
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for - I think it would help if you provided some more details about what you're trying to do and what happens when you try it. But you probably should neither `source` conda nor provide the path to it (i.e. just change that line to `conda activate envPython`).

Comment: I want to activate pyspark environment. When i access to my vm i have to execute two commands on terminal.
export SPARK_HOME="/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/"
source conda activate /home/mapr/miniconda3/envs/envPython

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how to it *cleanly* but here is something that works for me

- `chmod +x scripten`
- `source scripten`

This works fine for me (when activating `venv`).

---

### Edit

**scripten file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PYTHON_HOME="~/test/"
source ~/test/venv/bin/activate
```

**screenshot**

- top left: `source scripten` output
- bottom left: content of `test` dir
- right: script file

[image]

Comment: No it doesn't work for me

Comment: can you give me your file scripten please. I will compare it with my script @niko

Comment: Sure, let me edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your shebang to run bash in login mode, i.e.,

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
```

The Conda `activate` function is a shell function loaded through the shell resource file (e.g., `.bashrc`), so running a vanilla bash will not have it defined.